# Rails User model has_many activities (observer) but should also be observed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, polymorphism, observers

I'm running into an issue with an existing `ActiveRecord::Observer` model that records various `Activities` of a `User` the site. Everything was working really well, until I tried to `observe` the `User` class with the same `Activity` model that it uses to `observe` other models. Consider that:

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :item, :polymorphic => true
end

class ActivityObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
    observe :billing, :call, :vanity_number
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments
    has_many :activities
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :activities, :as => :item
end
```

The above worked fine. A query for `User.activities` would return rows of `Comment` `Activities`. As soon as I added `:user` to the `observe` method in `ActivityObserver` and changed `has_many :activities` in the `User` model to `has_many :activities, :as => :item`, `User.activities` would only return rows that were activities pertaining to that `User` instance and **not** any `Comments`

Why is this? What can I do to get this working as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you changed

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :activities
end
```

to

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :activities, :as => :item
end
```

it is now looking at the `item_id` field in the activities table where the type field is User to pull back activities where `item_id = users.id`. Before it was looking at the `user_id` field in activities.  Since the `item_id` field and type field cannot have two values, you made it so that an activity points at either a user or a comment. It can't be both.